# How to set string with spaces (from contents of a file) in a variable using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this code that reads the content of a file and set all the contents in a variable.

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%h in ('type C:\user\userfiles\title.txt') do (
set title=%%h
)echo %title%
```

Example contents of title.txt

```
AAAA BBBB CCCC
```

Now, It always display the word before the first space. How to display all contents of a file in variable **title**?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that there should be no delimiters in the `FOR` parameters, otherwise a space will be used and only pick up the first value:

```
REM Pick up a single token with no delimiters.
REM This will read the entire line of the file.
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%h in (`type "C:\user\userfiles\title.txt"`) do set title=%%h
echo %title%
```

Note that if the file has multiple lines, only the *last* line will be set to the `%title%` variable.

If you want to then turn around and use the result of `%title%` as a parameter to a program, make sure you put it in quotes as it may contain spaces:

```
SomeProgram.exe "%title%"
```

Comment: @PeterS - I just tested exactly what I have posted in my answer and it worked. If you copy/paste the answer exactly, what do you get as the result?

Comment: I just figured out the prob. When Im trying to echo the result, result are as expected. however, Im passing %title% into another variable (%4). But the word before the first space was passed. How to solve this? I want to pass the value, I only echo'ed the value in order to test

Comment: I already tried that solution before but im getting this error
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @PeterS - Please update your question with the call you are attempting to make with the `%title%` variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66791/discussion-between-jason-faulkner-and-peters).